# Merge intervals

Tags: java, programming-challenge, interview-questions, interval

> Given a collection of intervals, merge all overlapping intervals.
>
> For example,
>
> Given [1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18],
>
> return [1,6],[8,10],[15,18].

[GitHub](https://github.com/Ramblers-Code/interviewcake/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bulldozer/kata/MergingRanges.java)

```
public class MergingRanges {

    public static class Interval {
        int start;
        int end;

        public Interval(int start, int end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        public static Interval newInterval(int start, int end) {
            return new Interval(start, end);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(start, end);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof Interval) {
                Interval other = (Interval) o;
                return this.start == other.start && this.end == other.end;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder("(start").append(start).append(",end=").append(end).append(")").toString();
        }
    }

    public static List<Interval> mergeRanges(List<Interval> intervals) {
        if (intervals.size() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        intervals.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.start));
        List<Interval> mergedIntervals = new ArrayList<>();

        Interval pastInterval = intervals.get(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < intervals.size(); i++) {
            Interval currentInterval = intervals.get(i);

            if (currentInterval.start <= pastInterval.end) {
                // if the past interval can be merged with the current interval
                if (currentInterval.end > pastInterval.end) {
                    // this means currentInterval finishes outside of the past-intervals limit
                    Interval newInterval = new Interval(pastInterval.start, currentInterval.end);
                    pastInterval = newInterval;
                }
            } else {
                // as the past interval cannot be merged within the current interval, its the beginning of new interval
                mergedIntervals.add(pastInterval);
                pastInterval = currentInterval;
            }
        }
        mergedIntervals.add(pastInterval);

        return mergedIntervals;
    }

}


public class MergingRangesTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldBeMergedWhenTheyJustTouchesTheBoundary() {
        //
        // [Meeting(1, 2), Meeting(2, 3)]
        // These meetings should be merged, although they don't exactly "overlap"—they just "touch."
        //
        List<Interval> mergedIntervals = MergingRanges.mergeRanges(Arrays.asList(newInterval(1, 2), newInterval(2, 3)));
        assertEquals(newInterval(1, 3), mergedIntervals.get(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeCalculatedCorrectlyWhenOneIntervalIsSubsumedByTheOther() {
        //
        // Notice that although the second meeting starts later, it ends before the first meeting ends.
        // Does your method correctly handle the case where a later meeting is "subsumed by" an earlier meeting?
        //
        List<Interval> mergedIntervals = MergingRanges.mergeRanges(Arrays.asList(newInterval(1, 5), newInterval(2, 3)));
        assertEquals(newInterval(1, 5), mergedIntervals.get(0));

        // here (1,10) contains the rest of the interval, can we handle this?
        mergedIntervals = MergingRanges.mergeRanges(Arrays.asList(newInterval(1, 10), newInterval(2, 6), newInterval(3, 5), newInterval(7, 9)));
        assertEquals(newInterval(1, 10), mergedIntervals.get(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void mergeRanges() throws Exception {
        List<Interval> mergedIntervals = MergingRanges.mergeRanges(Arrays.asList(newInterval(0, 1), newInterval(3, 5), newInterval(4, 8), newInterval(10, 12), newInterval(9, 10)));

        //   [Meeting(0, 1), Meeting(3, 8), Meeting(9, 12)]
        assertEquals(newInterval(0, 1), mergedIntervals.get(0));
        assertEquals(newInterval(3, 8), mergedIntervals.get(1));
        assertEquals(newInterval(9, 12), mergedIntervals.get(2));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>             if (currentInterval.start <= pastInterval.end) {
>                 // if the past interval can be merged with the current interval
>                 if (currentInterval.end > pastInterval.end) {
>                     // this means currentInterval finishes outside of the past-intervals limit
>                     Interval newInterval = new Interval(pastInterval.start, currentInterval.end);
>                     pastInterval = newInterval;
>                 }
>             } else {
>                 // as the past interval cannot be merged within the current interval, its the beginning of new interval
>                 mergedIntervals.add(pastInterval);
>                 pastInterval = currentInterval;
>             }
> ```

This is quite a minor nit-pick, but where nested `if`s can be avoided it can make the code more readable:

```
        if (currentInterval.start > pastInterval.end) {
            // as the past interval cannot be merged within the current interval, its the beginning of new interval
            mergedIntervals.add(pastInterval);
            pastInterval = currentInterval;
        }
        else if (currentInterval.end > pastInterval.end) {
            // this means currentInterval finishes outside of the past-intervals limit
            Interval newInterval = new Interval(pastInterval.start, currentInterval.end);
            pastInterval = newInterval;
        }
```

Also, IMO `newInterval` is pointless, so I would make the further simplification of eliminating it to get:

```
        if (currentInterval.start > pastInterval.end) {
            // as the past interval cannot be merged within the current interval, its the beginning of new interval
            mergedIntervals.add(pastInterval);
            pastInterval = currentInterval;
        }
        else if (currentInterval.end > pastInterval.end) {
            // this means currentInterval finishes outside of the past-intervals limit
            pastInterval = new Interval(pastInterval.start, currentInterval.end);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things:

- It seems the global structure could be easier understood by pulling out `Interval` as a top level class and then creating an `IntervalList` class (maybe as a child of `List`). `IntervalList` could then have a dummy constructor which takes nothing and creates an empty list plus an `addInterval` method which adds a single `Interval` to the list. This way as far as I can tell nothing has to be static and the merge code can be simpler.
- The `toString` method is redundant.
- `shouldBeCalculatedCorrectlyWhenOneIntervalIsSubsumedByTheOther` tests subsumption with both a single and multiple intervals. To me this is a hint that the refactoring suggestion at the top of this list will simplify things, since the second part of that test is pointless if the looping happens in the caller.
- `mergeRanges` tests various combinations of intervals, and like `shouldBeCalculatedCorrectlyWhenOneIntervalIsSubsumedByTheOther` should be redundant after a refactoring.
- In general, names like `shouldBeCalculatedCorrectlyWhen…` are not helpful. First, obviously you aren't going to test when things are calculated *incorrectly,* so it's a vacuous statement. Second, it's not the most precise statement you can make about what you expect it to do. From what I understand it seems the purpose is to verify that the original interval is returned when merged with a contained interval (pointing towards something like `shouldReturnOriginalIntervalAfterMergingWithSubsumedInterval`), alternatively that the `List` of `Interval`s is unchanged after merging with a contained interval (hinting at something like `shouldNotChangeIntervalWhenMergedWithSubsumedInterval`). I'm being deliberately vague here because it's very context dependent what the test should be called - the idea is to concisely give the reader as much information as possible about how the code should operate.
- Always test the entire result. The first test in `shouldBeCalculatedCorrectlyWhenOneIntervalIsSubsumedByTheOther` checks the first element of `mergedIntervals`, but it doesn't verify that that is the *only* element in there. It would be very easy for a bug to sneak in where there are more elements in the list than you are checking. In this case I would simply check equality of the entire `mergedIntervals`.

Comment: I understand your concerns regarding *shouldBeCalculatedCorrectlyWhen* however you have not really came up with the alternate convention what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

## `Interval` class

- Such a simple data-holding class should be immutable, thus the fields should be private and have getter methods.
- The static construction method `newInterval` is a bit pointless. All that it saves is a single space compared with the constructor. If you want to use such a method, it's usually custom to call it `of` and use it exclusively by making the actual constructor `private`.
- In the `equals` method it would be good idea to compare the object references first:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) {
          return true;
      }
      if (o instanceof Interval) {
          Interval other = (Interval) o;
          return this.start == other.start && this.end == other.end;
      }

      return false;
  }
  ```
- In the `toString` method, simply use string concatenation:

  `"(start" + start + ",end=" + end + ")"`

  It better readable and the compiler will make a StringBuilder out of it internally anyway.

## `mergeRanges` method

- The method should have a signature as "wide" as possible. Since the order of the intervals isn't relevant, it would make sense to use `Collection` instead of `List` as the input and return parameters.
- The `sort` modifies the input list, something you should avoid, since the caller may not expect it. Better would be to create a sorted copy (which you'd have to do anyway, if you use a `Collection` as an input type). For this it would make sense to use a `SortedSet` have the `Interval` class implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

---

```
public static class Interval implements Comparable<Interval> {

    // Requires the getters to be defined
    private static Comparator<Interval> NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparingInt(Interval::getStart)
        .thenComparing(Interval::getEnd);


    // ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Housenumber other) {
      return NATURAL_ORDER_COMPARATOR.compare(this, other);
    }
}
```

---

- Merging to intervals seems to be a common operation, that could be useful outside of this algorithm, so I'd remove it and place it into the `Interval` class:

---

```
public Optional<Interval> merge(Interval other) {
  if (this.end > other.start || this.start < other.end) {
     return Optional.of(new Interval(Math.min(this.start, other.start)), Math.max(this.end, other.end));
  }
  return Optional.empty();
}
```

---

And the loop becomes:

---

```
for (int i = 1; i < intervals.size(); i++) {
        Interval currentInterval = intervals.get(i);

        Optional<Interval> newInterval = pastInterval.merge(currentInterval);
        if (newInterval.isPresent()) {
            pastInterval = newInterval.get();
        } else {
            mergedIntervals.add(pastInterval);
            pastInterval = currentInterval;
        }
    }
    mergedIntervals.add(pastInterval);
}
```

---

(This is not a nice use of Optional. If you don't like it, you can have the `merge` method just as well return `null`.)

(Also, all code is untested).